# Geojson como Tilelayer en leaflet

Tags: php, html, leaflet, geojson, mapa

Buen dia a todos,

Soy nuevo en programación y estoy intentando insertar un mapa en mi aplicacion, para esto he usado la libreria leaflet, para no saturar el servidor de OSM he querido alojar las tiles por mi cuenta, las raster tiles pesan bastante para un aplicacion, por esto he intentado usar el Geojson, por favor si pudieran despejar mi duda con lo siguiente:

¿Puedo usar Geojson como tilelayer en mi pagina web? aclaro, he visto ejemplos de como usan el geojson pero para mostrar puntos y lineas, lo que quiero es mostrar el mapa como tal pero con geojson, no con raster tiles (z,x,y.png).

si es asi ¿podrian hacerme el favor y guiarme como puedo hacerlo? ya lo he intentado y no lo he logrado.

Si no puedo usar el geojson para mostrar el mapa como tal, ¿que otro formato puedo usar?, he querido usar el .pbf pero no he encontrado forma alguna de hacerlo funcionar en mi proyecto.

detalles de mi proyecto:

1. Proyecto creado en laravel.
2. me es esencial mostrar un mapa ya que es para poder trazar rutas donde el mensajero va a llevar su domcilio y el cliente pueda rastrear en tiempo real donde va el mensajero.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda y guia.